# reload master table after alert box enter IOS

Tags: uitableview, ios7, master-detail

I have a master detail app. In the master, i am loading a uialertview and on pressing ok, the value that i enter needs to go to the table and refresh the master table. I tried [self.tableView reloadData], but it is not working. Can anyone suggest any ways to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Are u sure that your value is in the dataset when u use reloadData?

Check also that the reloadData reaches the right tableView.